# Calling a POST API fron node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, node-rest-client

I am a beginner with nodeJS.

What I am trying to do:

I have a POST API hosted and when I call it using postman, it gives me proper response as shown in image below:

[image]

But when I try to hit it using the NodeJS node-rest-client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) it is giving me an irrelevant large object as below:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ],
     data: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
```

I need help to get my proper object and I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Below is my code to call REST API:

```
app.get('/notes', cors(), function(req, res) {

    var args = {
                "hiveMachineIp": "192.168.0.110",
                "hiveMachinePort": "10000",
                "hiveUsername": "nt",
                "hivePassword": "",
                "hiveDatabaseName": "default",
                "hiveTableName": "transactions_24m",
                "hiveAggregationColumn": "customerid",
                "hiveAggregationFunction": "HISTOGRAM",
                "hiveAggregationHistogramBin": "5"
            };

    var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

    var client = new Client();

    client.post("http://163.47.152.170:8090/MachinfinityDataPreparation/machinfinitydataprep/hiveDataAggregation/", args, function (data, response) {
        // parsed response body as js object 
        // console.log(data);
        // raw response 
        console.log(response);
    });

    // registering remote methods 
    client.registerMethod("postMethod", "http://163.47.152.170:8090/MachinfinityDataPreparation/machinfinitydataprep/hiveDataAggregation/", "POST");

    client.methods.postMethod(args, function (data, response) {
        // parsed response body as js object 
        // console.log(data);
        // raw response 
        console.log(response);
    });

})
```

Comment: My guess would be that you're somehow dumping the client, not the response from the server that client is receiving. If you don't mind share part of your client code that is responsible for creating rest client and the request.

Comment: Issue is resolved using axios but I would still like to know what's wrong in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios](http://=https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) like this.

```
axios.post('/user', {
  firstName: 'Fred',
  lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: This did work for me. But, what's the reason that earlier it did not work if anyone can explain?

Comment: @AnKarthik Because you try to print raw response data. It contains every infomation and data related to your request and response.

Comment: @AnKarthik If you want to get response body data only, make uncomment `console.log(data)` and remove `console.log(response)` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Inside your code you're doing your request twice, once by `client.post` then by calling `client.methods.postMethod` that was previous registered. You should do one or the other, and `response` variable in each of callbacks comes from http client and it is not your raw json response. Your data has been already parsed and it sits in `data` variable.

In order to send one post request to your rest server you should use either `client.post` or register your method by `client.registerMethod` and then `client.methods.registeredMethodName` to send request.

When you need to send the same post request multiple times in your code then define a function that will handle response for that request, for instance:

```
function handleResponseA(data, response) {
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        switch(response.statusCode){
            case 404:
                console.log("Page not found.");
            break;

            case 500:
                console.log("Internal server error.");
            break;

            default:
                console.log("Response status code: " + response.statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

And then for `client.post`:

```
client.post("http://163.47.152.170:8090/MachinfinityDataPreparation/machinfinitydataprep/hiveDataAggregation/", args, handleResponseA);
client.post("http://163.47.152.170:8090/MachinfinityDataPreparation/machinfinitydataprep/hiveDataAggregation/", args, handleResponseA);
```

And to accomplish it by registered method, register method by:

```
client.registerMethod("postMethod", "http://163.47.152.170:8090/MachinfinityDataPreparation/machinfinitydataprep/hiveDataAggregation/", "POST");
```

And then invoke registered method:

```
client.methods.postMethod(args, handleResponseA);
client.methods.postMethod(args, handleResponseA);
```